# /manage.py celeryd : IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: django

When I try to run `python /manage.py celeryd  -B -l info`

I will get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/ansible_ui/manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/python/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/python/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/python/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/management/base.py", line 77, in run_from_argv
    return super(CeleryCommand, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/opt/python/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 238, in run_from_argv
    parser = self.create_parser(argv[0], argv[1])
  File "/opt/python/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 219, in create_parser
    option_list=self.option_list)
  File "/opt/python/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/management/base.py", line 107, in option_list
    if x._long_opts[0] not in self.skip_opts]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have some issues between the versions of `celery`, `django-celery` and `django`. An old [ticket of 2013-11-13](https://github.com/celery/django-celery/issues/285) about the same error while using `django-celery`.

Try updating these packages or "playing" around with the versions of the required packages. If this does not help, please update your question with the packages versions installed on your machine or your `virtualenv` by executing `pip freeze`.